# Jupyter notebook randomly stops utilizing all CPU cores

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, cpu-usage

I am currently doing a simple regression task (No ML libraries involved, just my own code) for a homework assignment. The problem is Jupyter sometimes uses 95%+ of my CPU (this is good, I have a 8600k which i would like to utilize) but often decides not to use any extra thread at all and remains at a steady 20% usage. My feedback loop gets increased 6 times over just because of this.

I have looked around for any jupyter related settings that might be relevant but found none. Is there any explanation for this problem?

EDIT:
Here's the code i'm currently using. The data passed is a 30000x36 np array. I don't know how jupyter parallels this but hey, it does it sometimes.

```
def hyp(theta, X):
    return X.dot(theta)

def cost_function(theta,X,Y):
    return (1.0 / ( 2 * X.shape[0] ) )  * np.sum(  (hyp(theta, X) - Y ) ** 2 ) 


def derivative_cost_function(theta, X, Y):
    e = hyp(theta, X) - Y
    return (1.0 / X.shape[0]) * X.T.dot(e)


def GradientDescent(X, Y, maxniter=400000):

    nexamples = float(X.shape[0])

    thetas = np.ones(X.shape[1],)
    alpha = 0.001

    print("Before:", cost_function(thetas, X, Y))

    print_iter = 100
    for i in range (maxniter):

        dtheta = derivative_cost_function(thetas, X, Y)
        thetas = thetas - alpha * dtheta

        if i % print_iter == 0:
            print(i, cost_function(thetas, X, Y))

    print("After:", cost_function(thetas, X, Y))
    return thetas
```

Comment: Do you have sample code that can help reproduce this issue?

Comment: just made an edit with the code i'm using, hope that helps somehow

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a numpy issue than a jupyter issue. Take a look at https://roman-kh.github.io/numpy-multicore/ to make numpy use more cores.

Comment: yeah you're right, it must be a numpy issue. I spent the past few hours looking at various git issues and tried a few solutions, including installing the intel distribution for python for Intel MKL. Nothing seems to have fixed it thus far. Oh well, I'll keep looking and update here if I find something. Thanks for the help.